Halo around texture with alpha channel
I'm looking for any ways to remove, or at least reduce a white halo around texture (leaf border). It's not visible on the ground (and sky) background (1st picture), but it's noticeable on the 2nd picture:
1st image
2nd image
This tree is a 3D model I'm trying to use in a free computer game. I'm using an alpha channel for a leaf texture which I put on a mesh plane. I tried several objects and textures, and notice the white halo. I'm not sure if it's possible to remove it, or if it depends on the game, but I'd like to try any ways to check them.

DirectX Transparent textures - Making plants look good
